# How to make service worker network first then cache

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to set up pwa app. My `sw.js` is

```
var urlsToCache = [
    '/danger/index.html',
'/danger/css/main.css',
'/danger/css/fontawesome-all.min.css',
'/danger/css/font.css'
];

var CACHE_NAME = 'progressive';

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then(function (cache) {
                return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
            })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
            return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
                return response || fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
                    cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
                    return response;
                });
            });
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
            return fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
                cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
                return response;
            });
        })
    );
});
```

I want to make sw check for first network, then cache. I got a code from net.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(async function() {
    try {
      return await fetch(event.request);
    } catch (err) {
      return caches.match(event.request);
    }
  }());
});
```

How to implement it in my `sw.js`.  I asked it because my app not updating the website content in network enabled mode also.

Comment: It looks like you have multiple `fetch` handlers, I think this will cause issues as the browser doesn't know which one should handle the fetch.

Comment: @abraham How to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Browser will always reach out to network first and get the service-worker.js     
I would suggest you to use Workbox instead of manually writing all these code.
[Workbox documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox)

We should not cache service-worker file as that is a source of truth for browser to know whether any other files have changed. Usually a service-worker file will have a series of files that are cached along with their hashes. When service worker file changes, then browser knows that it needs to take update from server.

Thanks